# How to remove multiple slashes in all URIs using mod_rewrite (apache2)?

Tags: regex, url, url-rewriting, webserver, apache2

I am trying to remove all double slashes from URIs within apache2. My approach works perfectly fine for any URI which doesn't contain a trailing slash or filename but fails on the latter.

**Disclaimer:** I'm not an expert in regular expressions yet - perhaps that's the problem.

**Working:**
 http://localhost////test -> rewritten to -> http://localhost/test
 http://localhost//////test////test -> rewritten to -> http://localhost/test/test

**Broken (both URIs are *working* but not *rewritten*):**
 http://localhost/////test/////test///// -> no rewrite at all
 http://localhost/////test/////test/test.html -> no rewrite at all

**Excerpt of my apache2 configuration:**

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)//(.*)
        RewriteRule (.*) %1/%2 [R=301,L]
</Directory>
```

I tried every single approach I was able to find but **every** one did only achieve a replacement of the multiple slashes when no filename or trailing slash is attached to the URI. I also checked my DevTools in Firefox and Chromium to see whether a 301 redirect happens on the non-working URIs but it doesn't.

I also have no .htaccess files within my folders in /var/www/html.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the slash between the first and second regex match group (`%1/%2` -> `%1%2`) and I also escaped the slashes within the regex (even though apache seems to handle it without them as well).

I also replaced the 301 redirect with a 302 one for testing. Keep in mind to change it for production usage.

Here is a snippet containing it as a macro you can use if you run into the same problem: [GitHub](https://github.com/bartscherer/apache2-strip-multiple-slashes)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was just thinking about matching more than 2 slashes with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST} (.*?)/{2,}(.*)` so that if you have `http://localhost//////test` you don't have multiple redirections but just one. I didn't test it. It's just an idea :-) But I then was thinking about the fact that if you have a path with multiple parts containing several slashes then you'll still have multiple redirections, which is not so nice. I wonder if there's not a better way to it, like a kind of "find and replace and then redirect".